# Laravel eloquent: using multiple when() to select with multiple dynamic conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a search function like that:

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
    $query = Member::select('members.*', 'profiles.belongs', 'profiles.position')
        ->leftJoin('profiles', 'members.id', '=', 'profiles.member_id');
    if (!empty($data['belongs'])) {
        $query->where('profiles.belongs', 'like', '%' . $data['belongs'] . '%');
    }
    if (!empty($data['user_id'])) {
        $query->where('members.user_id', '=', $data['user_id']);
    }
    if (!empty($data['name'])) {
        $query->where('members.last_name', 'like', '%' . $data['name'] . '%')
                ->orWhere('members.first_name', 'like', '%' . $data['name'] . '%');
    }
    $query->groupBy('members.id');
    switch ($request->field) {
        case 'belongs':
            $query->orderBy('profiles.' . $request->field, $request->type);
            break;
        case 'position':
            $query->orderBy('profiles.' . $request->field, $request->type);
            break;
        case 'name':
            $query->orderBy('members.last_name', $request->type);
            $query->orderBy('members.first_name', $request->type);
            break;
        default:
            $query->orderBy('members.' . $request->field, $request->type);
    }
        $members = $query->paginate($request->number_of_item);
        return $members;
    }
```

As you can see, this search function has 3 inputs: user_id, belongs, and name. I had expected that it will work as an AND condition, but with the "name" input it is not. I have 3 user like that:

```
user_id      first_name      last_name       belongs
1            a               b               org1
2            c               b               org2
3            c               a               null
```

For example:
If I search with user_id = 1, belongs = org and name = a, it will return user 1 & 3 (expected just user 1).
What did I wrong? All suggestions will be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's turned out to be quite simple. I have solved it myself by fixing this:

```
$query->where('members.last_name', 'like', '%' . $data['name'] . '%')
                ->orWhere('members.first_name', 'like', '%' . $data['name'] . '%');
```

to:

```
$query->where(function($q) use ($data) {
                $q->where('members.last_name', 'like', '%' . $data['name'] . '%')
                    ->orWhere('members.first_name', 'like', '%' . $data['name'] . '%');
            });
```